# Pseudo-alternate series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a non-increasing sequence of positive real numbers and $\varepsilon_i = \{\pm 1\},\ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \varepsilon_i a_i$ is convergent.
Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+...+\varepsilon_n) a_n=0$?

**Edit:** Some years later I found the same problem in *[Problems and Theorems in Analysis I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61983-0)*, Problem 139.

Comment: What's the context for this problem? For which sequences do you know this works?

Comment: This is clearly true for absolute convergent series. 

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  What have you tried to verify/disprove the contention?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.19

Comment: I agree it looks like a homework problem -- and the question doesn't even come with a list of things the poster managed to prove...

Comment: It is not a homework problem. I had the problem discussed with some of my friends during a math contest. We weren't able to prove or disprove it. This was two years ago...
I haven't posted any details, because I didn't manage to get very far with it. It is obvious that $a_n \to 0$. Then if the sequence $(\varepsilon_1+..+\varepsilon_n)$ is bounded, the result is obvious. 
That's what I could get so far. 

I remember proving that if the sequence $(\varepsilon_1+..+\varepsilon_n)$ is bounded from below or above, the result also follows, but I don't remember exactly how I did that. 

Comment: I still think it is close to a homework problem, but try this idea.  Pick a bounding function h(n) that goes to zero slowly, say 1/ln(ln(n)).  Pick a_i mostly constant and ensure that the partial sums stay between 0 and h(n).  If the partial sum is s_i and s_i + E_i*a_i is within the bounds, change the i to i+1 on the last term.  Else, for i+1, change the sign and set a_{i+1} to a_i/3, or whatever grows smaller than h(n) faster.  I think you will get a disproof.  For liminf though, I believe it is true.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.20

Comment: I would expect there to be some way to prove this with summation by parts.

Comment: Do you know a summation by parts proof for the series with positive terms? 

Comment: If you mean all of the signs are $+1$, then yes, but I don't see how to remove the reliance on positivity yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be more than welcome on AoPS, College Playground. For MO, it is hardly appropriate.

The statement is always true. Start with the fact that if the sums $\sum_{i=k}^m b_i$ ($1\le k\le m\le N$) are bounded by $\delta$ and $u_i$ is an increasing sequence of numbers on $[1,2]$, then the sums $\sum_{i=k}^m b_i u_i$ are bounded by $2\delta$. Now, split the set of indices into intervals of length $N_j$ such that the last $a$ in each interval is at most twice less than the first $a$ in each interval and the next $a$ is smaller. Let $A_j$ be the starting $a$ of the $j-th$ interval. The observation we made shows that the supremum of the sums of $\epsilon$'s over all subintervals of the $j$-th interval times $A_j$ is  at most $2\delta_j$ where $\delta_j\to 0$ (tails get small). This tells us that we need only show that the limit is $0$ over the indices corresponding to the block beginnings. Now, what happens for that subsequence is that whatever product we had for $j$ gets divided by at least $2$ when we pass to $j+1$, after which we add at most $2\delta_j$. It remains to note that if you start with any number and do a sequence of steps each of which is division by 2 followed by adding a number that gets closer and closer to $0$, you will get closer and closer to $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the details later, but I suppose you are correct. :)

Comment: I wrote a detailed version of your answer here: http://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/pseudo-alternate-series/

Answer (score 1):

No. If $\epsilon_i = 1,$ for all $i$ and $a_i = 0$ for $i$ not a perfect square, and $a_{k^2} = 1/k^2,$ then your limit is not zero, and the series is convergent. If you don't like $0,$ make the non-square $a_i$ some arbitrary small positive sequence.

**EDIT** however, if in the OP you replace $\lim$ by $\liminf,$ I am not sure what the answer is.

Comment: Actually the original post asks for $a_i$ to be monotonic, which is similar in spirit to your liminf, I think.

Comment: @JBL: oops, didn't read it carefully...